# barplot an ordinal variable grouped by quantile of an other numerical one

Tags: r, group-by, bar-chart, quantile

I have an ordinal variable with values A, B, C. I would like to draw a grouped barplot (in percent) with on x-axis the four quantiles (0-25%,25-50%,50-75%,75-100%) and for each one, three bars one per letter A, B and C and on y-axis the percentage of A or B or C per quantile.
How can i do with R without using ggplot ?

Comment: Thank you. The graph is exactly as I want it to be but I wasn't clear enough about the data. In fact, I have a dataset with two variables one ordinal ans one numerical :  ordinal <- factor(sample(LETTERS[1:3], 100, replace = TRUE), ordered = TRUE)  numerical <- 100*runif(100)  and I would like to present the ordinal variable grouped by quartiles of the numerical one.

Answer (score 0):

I may have misunderstood your concept of quantiles, since you only have 3 factor levels, so you might have to adjust that part. Here, I simply chopped a vector containing the 3 levels into 4 groups, representing the quantiles.

You can then use `barplot` with the `beside = TRUE` option to have grouped (and not stacked) bars:

```r
set.seed(123)
vals <- split(factor(sample(LETTERS[1:3], 100, replace = TRUE), ordered = TRUE), 
              gl(4, 25, labels = paste0("Q", 1:4)))
vals <- do.call(cbind, lapply(vals, function(x) prop.table(table(x))*100))
barplot(vals, legend.text = LETTERS[1:3], las=1, beside = TRUE, 
        args.legend = list(x="bottomright"), ylab="Percent")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-05-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

**Edit:**

If you have a numerical value to get the quantiles from, you could do something like:

```r
set.seed(123)
vals <- factor(sample(LETTERS[1:3], 100, replace = TRUE), ordered = TRUE)
nums <- 100*runif(100)
qts <- Hmisc::cut2(nums, g=4)
levels(qts) <- paste0("Q", 1:4)
barplot(
    do.call(rbind, setNames(lapply(split(qts, vals), 
        function(x) setNames(prop.table(table(x)) *100, paste0("Q", 1:4))), 
            LETTERS[1:3])), 
    legend.text = LETTERS[1:3], las=1, beside = TRUE, 
        args.legend = list(x="bottomright"), ylab="Percent")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-05-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you. The graph is exactly as I want it to be but I wasn't clear enough about the data. In fact, I have a dataset with two variables one ordinal ans one numerical :      ordinal <- factor(sample(LETTERS[1:3], 100, replace = TRUE), ordered = TRUE)  and       numerical <- 100*runif(100)   and I would like to present the ordinal variable grouped by quartiles of the numerical one.

Answer (score 0):

Let consider two variables of a dataset data

data$ordinal <- factor(sample(LETTERS[1:3], 100, replace = TRUE), ordered = TRUE)

and

data$numerical <- 100*runif(100)

To create subgroups around the median, I did

data$groupbymedian<-ifelse(data$numerical>median(data$numerical),1,0)

and then to plot :

barplot(table(data$ordinal,data$groupbymedian), beside = TRUE, legend = levels(data$ordinal))

To create subgroups around the 4 quartiles, I did

data <- within(data, groupbyquartile <- as.integer(cut(sep.diff.norm, quantile(sep.diff.norm, probs=0:4/4), include.lowest=TRUE)))
data$groupbyquartile

To plot, it is the same thing than above.